# Display a specific area of a Bitmap in imageView

Tags: android, listview, bitmap, resize, imageview

Here is my issue, I display in a ListView some Pictures come from web.
I would like to display in my ImageView only a specific area to my picture, without resizing it.

Here is a concret example :
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6J9AVdWXjwuWld5dU5CWXFSTjQ/edit?usp=sharing

I think it's possible with a Bitmap method, but I really don't know how to do this...

Thanks for your tips

Comment: have you tried this in your XML layout files for imageView => android:scaleType=""

Comment: Thanks for your help, Yes actually my imageView is in scaleType="FIT_XY", but it's not precisely what i expected...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the way to do this is to create a Bitmap object out of your source image. Here's an example:

```
File thumbFile = new File(thumbFileDir, imageName);
    //Bitmap source = your image
    Bitmap target= Bitmap.createBitmap(thumbSize, thumbSize,Config.ARGB_8888); //in my case the thumb image is square, use your dimensions instead of "thumbSize, thumbSize"
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(target);
    float hScale = thumbSize/(float)source.getWidth(); //again, thumb dimensions here
    float vScale = thumbSize/(float)source.getHeight(); //and here
    float scale = Math.max(hScale, vScale);
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.setScale(scale, scale);
    matrix.postTranslate(thumbSize/2 - source.getWidth()/2 * scale, thumbSize/2 - source.getHeight()/2 * scale); //and here
    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
    canvas.drawBitmap(source, matrix, new Paint());
```

The "target" object is what you are asking for

Comment: Thank you very much, I think i'm not far to success ;) To display my new image i have to do my_image_view.setImageBitmap(source); or target ?